# Is a poor homeless beggar exempt from his 5 daily salat?

Tags: salat, equality

Suppose a poor beggar who lives on streets and suffers from hunger everyday but gets by struggling everyday. He is also a Muslim, but I want to know if he is exempt from offering Salat due to his struggle. i.e. hunger, thirst, illnesses, mental stress and etc.

**If he is exempt from missing Salat why?**

If he is not exempt, how is it fair when you consider that in the hereafter he will after endure even more suffering to atone for missed Salat. Whereas a well off Muslim who can fulfill his obligatory duties will possibly have less suffering in this world and atone for less in the hereafter.

Therefore, the likely conclusion is that the poor beggar Muslims will be the losers in this life and the hereafter; in comparison to the well off Muslims. **How is this fair?**

**Please can someone offer an answer to this using authentic sources as reference.**

*Moderators please do not delete the comments in this question (As you've done in my previous question) or for any answers, as we are simply discussing the topic in more detail and addressing any ambiguities in their answers/ responses*

Thank You

Comment: Given that pretty much every single comment (now deleted) on the heavily-commented answer so far has been, at best, tangential to anything actually asked in this question, do take the time to actually focus your question to make it clear what you're *actually* asking for so nobody else has to waste their time posting insufficient answers. Also note, we are *not* a site for argument and debate.

Comment: @goldPseudo I have edited my question to give more context and also highlighted the key question. Also can you delete the answer below as it doesn't answer my question and doesn't give any authentic sources; which is a key part of my question.

Comment: You haven't *clarified* your question here so much as just went ahead and asked a completely new question, which would be much better off posted separately (assuming it's not just a dupe of https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/52146/22, which it really looks like). The existing answer was posted to your original question, which it does a fair job of answering, and deleting it just because you decided to move the goalposts wastes the effort they've already spent trying to answer you, which is hardly fair to them.

Comment: Read [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on the purpose and use of comments. Comments are not meant to last forever if you want to discuss you should move to chat. IMO your initial attempt was a good question, but with the last edition it just creates more confusion. If you have a follow-up question ask it as a new question instead of discussing it widely in comments.

Comment: @medi1Saif I understand, is there anyway I can move to chat on this website or do you mean on another website.

Comment: @JohnBob well I was referring to a the chat on SE, but this option requires some more rep.

Answer (score 3):

I can not give any proper hadith right now, but I know plenty of story of the companions of Muhammad (SM) who were very poor and did not have food to eat, did not have clothes to wear but they were told to perform their salat. Nobody is free from their salat, whatever is their conditions are.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points. If the relevant posts are unclear to the point that you need extensive discussion to explain how it answers the question, chances are the post needs to be edited.