# Our worship or lack of it neither adds nor lessens Allah's Mightiness

Tags: quran, reference-request, ibadah

> Abu Dharr reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying that Allah, the Exalted and Glorious, said:
>
> O My servants, even if the first amongst you and the last amongst you
>   and even the whole of human race of yours, and that of jinns even,
>   become (equal in) God-conscious like the heart of a single person
>   amongst you, nothing would add to My Power. O My servants, even if the
>   first amongst you and the last amongst you and the whole human race of
>   yours and that of the Jinns too in unison become the most wicked (all
>   beating) like the heart of a single person, it would cause no loss to
>   My Power. O My servants, even if the first amongst you and the last
>   amongst you and the whole human race of yours and that of jinns also
>   all stand in one plain ground and you ask Me and I confer upon every
>   person what he asks for, it would not. in any way, cause any loss to
>   Me (even less) than that which is caused to the ocean by dipping the
>   needle in it.
>
> **Reference    : Sahih Muslim**
>
> **The Book of Virtue, Enjoining Good Manners, and Joining of the Ties of Kinship**
>
> **Chapter: The Prohibition Of Oppression**
>
> [From sunnah.com:](https://sunnah.com/muslim/45/70)

What ayah(s) from Quran would be equivalent to the spirit of the above quoted hadith (and the title of this post)?

Comment: [If God is a perfect being why does he desire to be glorified](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46016/if-god-is-a-perfect-being-why-does-he-desire-to-be-glorified/46096#46096) has a certain relevance.

Comment: I think 4:131 fits my question. Would you care to turn it into an answer, or should I answer my own question?

Comment: It is up to you I'm actually not thinking to answer it as I'm about to go offline :)

Answer (score 1):

Closest which I've found:

*56. I have placed my trust in God, my Lord and your Lord. There is not a creature but He holds it by the forelock. My Lord is on a straight path.*

*57. If you turn away, I have conveyed to you what I was sent to you with; and my Lord will replace you with another people, **and you will not cause Him any harm**. My Lord is Guardian over all things.”*

Surah 11